# Error with Google Adsense on Firefox console

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

I have been trying to add this to my page and I am getting this error in Firefox under the JS errors section.

**An unsupported character encoding was declared for the HTML document using a meta tag. The declaration was ignored.**

My code is below

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345678987654321";
/* OAS home */
google_ad_slot = "123456789";
google_ad_width = 120;
google_ad_height = 240;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Comment: id link to note going to the site downloads a js file. should i include that on my site and link it somewhere ?

Comment: website can be seen [Here](http://www.officialacescottie.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the  section of your document, you're using a bad character encoding I guess, ( see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp )

Consider adding head section code for further help.

Comment: i already have that. on Google Chrome it says failed to load resource.